# SSIS 2 csv files into 1 csv file

Tags: sql-server, csv, merge, ssis, etl

I have 2 csv files which contain different headers and data (below is an example)

csv1

```
Name|PhoneExt|location
john,6754,office
```

csv2

```
EmployeeNo|Car|Reg
6754,astra,dk096hy
```

I want to join the two csv files and link the phone ext from csv 1 with the employee number from csv 2 and export to one csv file which contains the headers from both files and data.
I want this:

```
Name|PhoneExt|location|EmployeeNo|Car|Reg     
john,6754,office,6754,astra,dk096hy
```

what is the best way to do this. I have tried using a sort and a merge but I cant get the link on the phone ext and employee number working.
any advice would be grateful

Comment: In what way can you not get the link working? Don't know how to do it or not getting expected results?

Comment: you want merge join and just remember that data types are important.

Answer (score 1):

If i would do it, i would keep it as seperated as possible.

> 1. I would stage your 2 CSV Files into 2 SQL Tables. 
>      This enables you to always have staged data and you have it as it is from your source. For test purpose this gives you an advantage
> 2. Then i would join these 2 tables in an `OLEDB Source Tasks` so you get
>      the desired output.
> 3. Then i would use a `flat file destination` to create your new CSV file.

This is by far an simple and easy way to do it and then its clear what happends.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Merge Join transformation to achieve this, you can read more informations in the link above:

- https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-merge-join-transformation/

*Make sure that both columns has the same data type and case (both upper case or lower case)*